# Creating one-many relationship between street sections and car scans?

Tags: postgresql, one-to-many

I have two tables and need to create a one to many relationship between them. tlbsection represents a series of street sections as lines in a city. Each street section has its own id.
tlbscans represents a on street scan of a street section counting cars on it. I need to relate tlbscans to tlbsection as a street section and can have more than one scan. What is a good way to do this with with the example data below?

### tlbsections
ID(PK) | geom  | section  |

1       | xy    |     5713 |

2       | xy    |     5717 |

### tlbscans
section | a  | b   |

5713    | 30  |  19 |

5717    | 2   |   1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overwhelming question: Is the column `section` unique in `tlbsections`. If it is then create a *unique constraint* on it. Then create a FK on column `section` in table `tblscans' referencing. Assuming the tables already exist:

```
alter table tlbsections 
      add constraint section_uk
          unique section; 

alter table tblscans
      add constraint scans_section_fk 
          foreign key (section) 
          references tlbsections(section);
```

If column `section` unique in `tlbsections` is not unique then you *cannot* build a relationship as currently defined. Without much more detail, I suggest you add a  column to contain `tlbsections.id`, create a FK on the new column then drop column `section` tblscans.

```
alter table tblscans
      add tlbsections_id <data type>; 
   
alter table tblscans
      add constraint sections_fk 
          foreign key (tlbsections_id) 
          references tlbsections(id);

alter table tblscans
      drop column  section;
```

There may be other options, but not apparent what is provided.